# IST time format returns NAN in JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angular, date

```js
console.log(Date.parse('Wed Jul 07 04:49:10 IST 2021')); // returns NAN
console.log(Date.parse('Wed Jul 07 04:49:10 EDT 2021')); // working as expected
```

How to convert IST dateString (Wed Jul 07 04:49:10 IST 2021)  to number.

Comment: Use [ISO 8601 format](https://xkcd.com/1179/) if you can, to ensure correct conversion. If you only get this format, you need to either parse it into ISO 8601 or use a library to do it for you.

Comment: I'm more surprised either works. Can you not amend the source format to be ISO8601, as this is much more standard and better supported. For example: `2021-07-07T04:49:10+0530`

Comment: `Date.parse` expects _A string representing a simplification of the ISO 8601 calendar date extended format. (Other formats may be used, but results are implementation-dependent.)_

Comment: See [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Comment: @SalmanA— *Date.parse* must also support the formats produced by *Date.prototype.toString* (specified in ECMA-262) and *Date.prototype.toUTCString* (specified in RFC 7231 and generalised in ECMA-262). ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, spec doesn't prescribe `Date.parse()` to handle the timezone abbreviations. Only a few of those are supported by major `Date.parse()` implementations out-of-the-box, and EDT is one of them. The biggest issue with recognizing IST is that this abbreviation might actually mean three different things:

- [India Standard Time](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/ist) (Standard Time) (UTC +05:30)
- [Israel Standard Time](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/ist-israel) (Standard Time) (UTC +02:00)
- [Irish Standard Time](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/ist-ireland) (Daylight Saving Time) (UTC +01:00)

... so it's quite difficult to parse the source string in a deterministic way. So your best bet would be replacing IST with a numeric timezone identifier (`+05:30` for India Standard Time, for example).

Comment: @VLAZ— [*Date.parse*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date.parse) must also parse the format produced by [*Date.prototype.toString*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date.prototype.tostring) and [*date.prototype.toUTCString*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date.prototype.toutcstring), so there are 3 string formats it's required to parse (and everything else is implementation dependent). ;-)